# Jquery serialize and serializeArray is not working with google chrome

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have following html.

```
<fieldset id="fieldset-step_3">   
       <input type="text" value="2" id="rule_form-lead_time" name="rule_form[lead_time]"> 
       <select class="w50" id="rule_form-operator" name="rule_form[operator]">
            <option label="&lt;" value="&lt;">&lt;</option>
            <option selected="selected" label="&gt;" value="&gt;">&gt;</option>
       </select>
       <button type="button" id="next" name="next">Next</button>
</fieldset>
```

I use following jquery code for get values when click next button.

```
   $('#next').click(function () {
        var values = $('#fieldset-step_3').serialize();
        alert(values);          
   });
```

This code working for firefox 8 and opera 11.60 beta. But it does not work for google chrome 15.0.874.121.

Please help me. Give me another idea for get field-set values from jquery.

Comment: did u try using http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/ using a form?

Comment: Validate your HTML - http://validator.w3.org/ - And validate your JavaScript -  http://www.jshint.com/

Comment: @Ricardo Arruda - Yes i used it. It also has same result.

Comment: @kanishka - No i want only firfox and chrome.

Comment: @Asuraya have you tried what i said .  is alert(values); working in chrome ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have found a bug.  I tried this in Chrome 11 and saw the same thing.  If I serialize the form, it works.  If I serialize individual form elements, it works.  If I try to serialize a div containing all of the form elements, or your fieldset tag, it doesn't.

Comment: I scratched my head for a bit with this issue. It ended up being missing enctype="x-www-urlencoded" on the form tag which apparently Chrome needed to see. Firefox and others didn't have problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a simple way, but does the job, and u can customize it the way u want.

```
parseField = function( $object ){
  result = new Array();
  $object.find('select[value!=""], input[value!=""]').each(function(){
    var obj = {};
    obj.key = $(this).attr('name');
    obj.val = $(this).val();
    result.push( obj );
  });
  return result;
}
```

You can use it like:

```
var values = parseField( $('#fieldset-step_3') );
$.each(values, function(i,obj){
  alert( 'My key is: ' + obj.key + ' and my value: ' + obj.val );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

mmm try adding

```
<input type="text" value="2" id="rule_form-lead_time" name="rule_form[lead_time]" />
```

insted of

```
<input type="text" value="2" id="rule_form-lead_time" name="rule_form[lead_time]">
```

when validating this i found

```
end tag for "input" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified

…ut type="text" value="2" id="rule_form-lead_time" name="rule_form[lead_time]"> 


You may have neglected to close an element, or perhaps you meant to "self-close" an element, that is, ending it with "/>" instead of ">".
```

Answer (score 1):

I run into this today.
$('#formid').serialize(); works fine with firefox,but nothing came out in chrome.
After some tests,here's my answer:

in chrome,the form name and id must be the same to make serialize work.