# Serialize a form element showing null for Chrome but not IE

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have a function that when I use IE this works but in Chrome the for statement doesn't work because it is saying that the formElements is null.

```
var formElements = $(formID).serialize(true);

if(sizeOfJsonObject(formElements) <= 0){
 alert("error");
}

function sizeOfJsonObject(jsonObj){
   var size = 0;
   var x;
   for(x in jsonObj){
        //alert(x);
        size++;
    }
   return size;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What library are you using? The jQuery `.serialze()` method has nothing to do with JSON; it returns a string. (Also, you must declare both "x" and "size" with `var` in your function.)

Comment: This link could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166991/jquery-serialize-and-serializearray-is-not-working-with-google-chrome

Comment: What is `formID`? How does your markup look like?